# Updating checkbox on PreferenceActivity

Tags: android

How do I update my PreferenceActivity?

I've saved in the SharedPreferences the value of my CheckBox in an activity (in that case, true). And even if I go to other activities I can see that it's true. But, when I go to my PreferenceActivity, the checkbox is not checked, it's false. So what I want to know is, how do I load my SharedPreferences in my PreferenceActivity, and how do I update the CheckBox (load the value, and if it's true, set the CheckBox as checked).

Should I load it like this?

```
Shared Preferences SP = getSharedPreferences(DATA, MODE_PRIVATE);
fw = SP.getBoolean("fw", false);
```

But, how do I set the CheckBox true or false since I can't use findViewById?

EDIT:

Activity where I save the CheckBox value:

```
Editor edit = SP.edit();
edit.putBoolean("fw", fwbt.isChecked());
edit.commit();
```

My preference xml file:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="CheckBox FW"
    android:key="fw"
    android:summary="Estado do CheckBox" />
```

My preference Activity:

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        //Don't know what to do here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a solution, so I gave up. I've just created created a custom Preferences, it's way easier.

Anyway, I'll keep looking for a solution for this later.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `Editor` to modify the `SharedPreferences`.

**Example**

```
getSharedPreferences(DATA, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("fw", true).commit();
```

**Update**

You need to define the used `SharedPreferences` in the Activity, too.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(DATA);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I think that I may have expressed myself baddly. I've saved in the SharedPreferences the value of my CheckBox in an activity (in that case, true). And even if I go to other activities I can see that it's true. But, when I go to my PreferenceActivity, the checkbox is not checked, it's false. So what I want to know is, how do I load my SharedPreferences in my PreferenceActivity, and how do I update the CheckBox (load the value, and if it's true, set the CheckBox as checked).

Comment: Are you loading the XML file containing a `PreferenceScreen` with `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_classic_appearance)` and then the `CheckBoxPreference`'s state does not match the state stored to `DATA`? Did you define the key "fw" for the `CheckBoxPreference` in that configuration file?

Comment: I've edited my post with parts of my code. It's the same key,and I called `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.mypreferencexmlfile);`

Answer (score 0):

I have not use PreferenceActivity before but I think you simply need to implement it like any other activity.

```
public class PreferenceWithHeaders extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(IDOFBUTTON);
        ...  do whatever on checkbox

    }
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't give the CheckBoxPreference an id.

Answer (score 0):

You've mess it up - the PreferenceActivity writes/reads from the `SharedPreferences`. So in your activity do

```
Shared Preferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit = SP.edit();
edit.putBoolean("fw", fwbt.isChecked());
edit.commit();
```

and the change should be there in your PreferenceActivity.

Also :

```
SP.edit().putBoolean("fw", fwbt.isChecked()).commit();
```

will do